# MySQL #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create table then show the following error. But I can't found the error. I am new in Mysql Please help me..

SQL query:

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `files`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `post`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `offer` (    
 offer_id INT( 9 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 offer_category VARCHAR( 50 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL ,
 offer_type VARCHAR( 50 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL ,
 sub_category_id INT( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
 category_id INT( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
 state_id INT( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
 city_id INT( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
 location_id INT( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
 file_id INT( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
 title VARCHAR( 50 ) CHARACTER,
 description TEXT CHARACTER,
 date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
 exp_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
 shop_id INT( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
 status TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  offer_id )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =63;
```

the error is,

```
MySQL said: Documentation

        #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '  
          `description` text CHARACTER,
            `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TI' at line 22
```

Comment: `description TEXT` without `CHARACTER`, or specify a valid charset: `CHARACTER SET utf8`

Comment: Basically, what's happening is that you can't import an SQL dump. This doesn't look like you're creating all this on your own if you're so new to MySQL, which leads me to conclude that you're doing some paid work about things you know nothing about and you want free help from SO instead of learning experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issues :

1. `title` VARCHAR( 50 ) CHARACTER : VARCHAR(50) is enough , MySQL doesn't support this syntax.
2. `description` TEXT CHARACTER : use one TEXT or CHAR
3. Two columns can't have `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Try this one

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `offer` (

 `offer_id` INT( 9 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `offer_category` VARCHAR( 50 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL ,
 `offer_type` VARCHAR( 50 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL ,
 `sub_category_id` INT( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
 `category_id` INT( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
 `state_id` INT( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
 `city_id` INT( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
 `location_id` INT( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
 `file_id` INT( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
 `title` VARCHAR( 50 ) ,
 `description` TEXT ,
 `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
 `exp_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,
 `shop_id` INT( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
 `status` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `offer_id` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =63;
```